# set of dropdowns with same value - validation

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-select

I have a set of four select drop down's(`bootstrap selectpicker`) with same values one to ten with different ids and names ex.[`id="select1",id="select2"`].

How can I validate this dropdowns, so user can't select same value. Ex, if user has choosen 1 in first dropdown so i don't want allow him to choose 1 in rest of the dropdowns.

```
$("select").change(function() { var value = $(this).val();
//alert(value); $("select").not(this).find("option[value ="+value+"]").attr('disabled',true).selectpicker('refresh'); });
```

I tried above code but it is not working.

Comment: can you please share the html code

Comment: Disable element '1' in other 3 dropdown if '1' is selected in first dropdown by js. One way to do this.

Comment: sounds like a bad use for a drop down. Use checkbox.

Comment: you just remove the selected value from the other dropdowns

Comment: i am genrating the dropdown by using php

Comment: $("select").change(function() {   
         var value = $(this).val();
          //alert(value);
         $("select").not(this).find("option[value ="+value+"]").attr('disabled',true).selectpicker('refresh');
       });

Comment: i tried above code.but it is not working

Comment: check with if() condition if values match than give message

Comment: yes.i can do this with if condition but than my code will be bigger.i have to match dropdown 1 with 2,3,4.and again dropdown 2 with 1,3,4.etc

Comment: Added code posted by OP as comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the option:

```
$("select").click(function() { 
var value = $(this).val(); 
$("select").not(this).find("option[value ="+value+"]").remove(); //.prop('disabled', true);
$("select").not(this).selectpicker('refresh');
 });
```

Comment: only thing you missed is dot(.)- $("select")selectpicker('refresh');

Comment: This will remove options from the subsequent select pickers, but will not add options back in if someone changes their mind on the first select... If I pick option A on the first select box, option A will be disabled on selects 2, 3 and 4. But if I change my choice in the first select to B, A will still be disabled on selects 2, 3 and 4... (as well as B)

Comment: i have to check that

Comment: from the selectpiker documentation the prop method should work

Comment: so what is the solution for this

Comment: i used .attr('disabled',true) instead of remove()

Comment: works with that too, you where calling `selectpicker('refresh');` on the option that is why the select where not working